# Get specific value from $order object array

Tags: php, arrays

I did a var_dump from my Woocommerce $order variable. The result of this dump is: https://snippi.com/s/xkbxiyf

On line 436, you have to key `_enviso_selected_date`. How do you get the corresponding value on line 438 (`2021-10-28`) ?

I've managed to get the value with this:

```
$offer_date = $order->items[748]->get_data()['meta_data'][3]->get_data()['value'];
```

But the `748` changes on each order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access the required element in the $order array.
You can access an object as following:

```
$obj->name;
// or
$obj->{'name'};
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I echo the following: $order->_enviso_selected_date; because it seems nested.

Comment: Yes it's a multidimensional and nested array.
You can access elements in multidimensional arrays like this : $obj[xxx][xx2][xx3]. xxx, xx2,.. are the keys.

Use this page to beautify your var_dump. Then it's easier to detect the structure of the array: https://vardumpformatter.io/

$obj->{'name'}; was for objects in the array.

Comment: This is the output of the $order dump: https://vardumpformatter.io/en/shared/4f03d96c8237c30515c057e2d836a3e4

Comment: So is it correct to do it like this: $order['data']['items'] ... ?

Comment: Yes but only if an element is an array. If there is e.g. "object(XXX)(4) { .." you have to use "XXX ->" for the element. 
But if it's to complicate or annoying for you could work with the string:

`$ordervalue= var_export($order, true); //the var_dump is now in $ordervalue

$envisoIndex = strpos($ordervalue, "_enviso_selected_date"); //The position of enviso_selected_date in $ordervalue

$theDate = substr($ordervalue, $envisoIndex+45, 10); //2021-10-28 should be in theDate but probably the 45 is not correct. Just experiment with the number
`

Comment: I have managed to retrieve the value with this: $offer_date = $order->items[748]->get_data()['meta_data'][3]->get_data()['value']; But it only issue is that "748" changes for each order.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the shopify framework but try my method